# Using SFML with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sfml

Right now I'm trying to get SFML to work with my Visual Studio 2010, so I can start learning how to make windows applications and games using the libraries within SFML. I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/1.6/window-window.php) to open a new window, but my program seems to break instantly. I really don't know why :S. It seems to build and compile, but then breaks:

[image]

Edit: It breaks at this line: `App.Create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML Window");`

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>

int main ()
{
    sf::Window App;
    App.Create(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "SFML Window");
    bool Running = true;
    while (Running)
    {
        sf::Event Event;
        while (App.GetEvent(Event))
        {
            if (Event.Type == sf::Event::Closed)
                Running = false;

            if ((Event.Type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) && (Event.Key.Code == sf::Key::Escape))
                Running = false;

        }
        App.Display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Also, I should note:
On the SFML website, the tutorials for setting it up with Visual Studio seem to be for VS 2008 (Setting up SFML with VS). I managed to get a set of instructions for VS2010 and set it up. I used a short program to test if the SFML libraries were working:

```
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::Clock Clock;
    while (Clock.GetElapsedTime() < 5.f)
    {
        std::cout << Clock.GetElapsedTime() << std::endl;
        sf::Sleep(0.5f);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

^ This program worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SFML libraries are compiled for Visual Studio 2008.  If you use it with VS2010, it will 'kind of' work.  You'll get messages about a corrupted stack, and possibly other hard crashes when you call certain functions (like App.Clear()).

You need to either recompile the source code for the libraries yourself, or find a version where somebody else has done that.  I don't believe there's an 'official' source, but if you search the forums at the SFML site, you'll find some links to libs compiled for 2010.

Late answer, I know... but this question is still coming all the time.

Comment: Yup, you're right. I figured this out later and got a recompiled set of dlls. All works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the error you are getting here is because you used `Window` instead of `RenderWindow`.

Comment: If you're talking about the line:
sf::Window App;

...then I just tested your suggestion and it still doesn't work. The program doesn't even build completely using RenderWindow. It doesn't recognise it at all. Using Window it builds, but breaks upon execution.

Also, I fixed some of the links in the OP. I didn't realise that they broke when i pasted this.

Comment: `RenderWindow` is for 2D drawing. There's no drawing, it is ok to use a `Window`.